# SQL Error in android

Tags: android, sql

I'm currently trying to remove a row of data from my android database but am receiving an unusual error. The row looks like this in the table with name Timetable

_ID = (auto increment), MODULE = CM111, DAY = MONDAY, STARTTIME = 13:00, DURATION = 4 hours, TYPEOFSESSION = LAB, ROOM = PBS2

I'm using this code for my remove

```
private int removeEvent (String modulecodepicker){
    try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, MODULE + " = " + modulecodepicker, null);
    }catch(SQLiteException ex){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Broken", 10);
        toast.show();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is returning this SQL error

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: CM111: , while compiling: DELETE FROM timetable WHERE module = CM111

Thanks

Comment: The name of the column should not be quoted?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error ??

Answer (score 0):

you can create store procedure for the above , it would much safer and easier ,

whereas using inline prone to sql injection also

please refer for writing procs in sql lite

http://chriswolf.heroku.com/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Cross check it with a `SELECT 'CM111' from timetable` statement first. If it doesnt work then it is quite obvious your DELETE doesn't work.